# Symfony2 jms/i18n-routing-bundle and multiple hosts to one locale

Tags: symfony, routes, internationalization

I am using mentioned bundle in my application, and I would like to be able to configure it this way:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [en, de]
    strategy: custom
    hosts:
        en: [mydomain.com, subdomain.domain.com]
        de: mydomain.de
    redirect_to_host: false
```

so multiple domains to one locale. I would like to run two similiar websites at one application to have access to the 90% of the code which is similiar and same database. Any tips how could i achieve this? Or maybe there is other bundle/solution more accurate for my problem?

Comment: Did you try `en:mydomain.com en:subdomain.domain.com de:mydomain.de`

Comment: mydomain.com will be overrided by subdomain.domain.com (last occurence of 'en' locale in yml configuration)

Answer (score 0):

From the configuration you cannot bind multiple domains to one locale.
You can try to extend this class of the bundle:
`JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\Router\DefaultLocaleResolver`

You need to change this part:

```
public function resolveLocale(Request $request, array $availableLocales)
{
    if ($this->hostMap && isset($this->hostMap[$host = $request->getHost()])) {
        return $this->hostMap[$host];
    }
    ...
}
```

adding a more complex `hostMap` that supports multiple domains for the same locale.